# Group policy preference run once & membership change

Tags: group-policy

How exactly does the 'run once' option in group policy preferences work in relation to group membership changes?

Say I have item level targeting on a preference object inside a group policy, limiting the scope to a specific group. After this policy exists I add a computer to this group, putting it in scope.

Will this preference:

1. never run (since the group policy version number hasn't changed)
2. run only for the first time added to the group (since it's now literally run once)
3. run each time the group is added (for example the role changes and is removed from said group, and changes again later).

Ideally what I'm after is a policy that will make a specific set of changes - all via preferences - only immediately after a group membership is updated. The policy would reapply if added to a group a second time but not on any of the runs in between.

I'm not in a position to test this right now.